# How do you save contenteditable forms generated from the mongodb in meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, contenteditable

After a form is submitted, you can go to a manage page to edit the forms. The forms are displayed with the inputs submitted with the original form. I am using 'contenteditable' for the first time instead of using an 'edit' button for 'editmode.' The issue I'm having is saving the changes made.

I have a save button as a submit, but I get an error when it's trying to find the value. I've tried switching the html around with the value = to the collection instead of having it written in the actual cell. But then it shows nothing.

```
<form id="editInvoice">
...
<div class="row invoice-report-details-container" style="margin-top: 50px; clear: both">
   <div class="col s4">
      <span class="invoice-report-header-item-title">To</span>
       <p id="recipient" class="invoice-report-header-item-content" contenteditable="true" ><u>{{details.recipient}}</u></p>
   </div>

   <div class="col s4">
       <span class="invoice-report-header-item-title">Order Taken By</span>
       <p id="orderTakenBy" class="invoice-report-header-item-content" contenteditable="true" >{{details.orderTakenBy}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
...
</form>



 Template.SingleInvoiceDetails.helpers({
      details: ()=>{
        let id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        return Invoices.findOne({_id:id});
      },
    });

Template.SingleInvoiceDetails.events({  
'submit #editInvoice': function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    const target = event.target;
    const updateRecipient = target.recipient.value;
    const updateOrderTakenBy = target.orderTakenBy.value;

Meteor.call('updateJobInvoice',updateRecipient,updateOrderTakenBy)
}
});
```

I get an error message:

Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.submit #editInvoice (SingleInvoiceDetails.js:143)

Line 143 is code: const updateRecipient = target.recipient.value;

```
Meteor.methods({
updateJobInvoice: function(
    updateRecipient,
    updateOrderTakenBy
  ){
    Invoices.update({
      $set: {
      recipient: updateRecipient,
      orderTakenBy: updateOrderTakenBy,
      }
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use input field with type and name properties and use `new FormData()`:

```
<form id="editInvoice">
   ...
   <div class="row invoice-report-details-container" style="margin-top: 50px; clear: both">
   <div class="col s4">
     <span class="invoice-report-header-item-title">To</span>
     <input type="text name="recipient" value={{details.recipient}}class="invoice-report-header-item-content"/>
   </div>

   <div class="col s4">
     <span class="invoice-report-header-item-title">Order Taken By</span>
     <input type="text" name="orderTakenBy" value={{details.orderTakenBy}} class="invoice-report-header-item-content"/>
   </div>
</div>
... 
</form>


Template.SingleInvoiceDetails.events({  
  'submit #editInvoice': function(event,template){
     event.preventDefault();
     let data = new FormData(event.target)
     for(let i of data.entries()){
        data[i[0]] = i[1]
     }

     Meteor.call('updateJobInvoice',data.updateRecipient,data.updateOrderTakenBy)
  }
});
```

Or if you want use `p tag with contenteditable prop` only I can find out is:

```
Template.SingleInvoiceDetails.events({  
  'submit #editInvoice': function(event,template){
     event.preventDefault();
     const updateRecipient = document.getElementById('recipient').innerText;
     const updateOrderTakenBy = document.getElementById('orderTakenBy').innerText;
     const invoiceID = ....some invoice id....
     Meteor.call('updateJobInvoice',invoiceID, updateRecipient,updateOrderTakenBy)
   }
});
```

UPDATE:
Remember that your `updateJobInvoice` method should be on server side and from my point of view `$set` method should have `id` property. Hence, you should pass this `invoiceID` from client side (Template.SingleInvoiceDetails). I dont know you app structures and data flow, so I can't definitely solve your problem. But I some time ago I wrote simple CRUD App in meteor. It may be useful to you: https://github.com/varrior/meteorJS-To-do-app/tree/master/imports

server side e.g. (.../api/invoice.js)

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateJobInvoice: function(invoiceID, updateRecipient,updateOrderTakenBy){
    Invoices.update(invoiceID, {
      $set: {
         recipient: updateRecipient,
         orderTakenBy: updateOrderTakenBy,
      }
    });
  },
})
```

Comment: When I use the 2nd example for the contenteditable prop, I get the server message error: Exception while invoking method 'updateJobInvoice' [object Object].  I have added the method to the original post. And a client side error message: Error invoking Method 'updateJobInvoice' errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 500, reason: "

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe it will be useful for you